# Animating a dropdown with vueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, transition

I've created a navigation with a mouseover and mouse leave which triggers boolean to show my dropdown.

I want my list to trigger a different animation to the surrounding box, but I can't seem to trigger different transitions.

my transition only works on if i put the v-if on the list and when I put it the whole div it won't work.

I've mocked up an example in jsfiddle

```
<div id="app">

 <div class="nav">
  <div @mouseover="showProducts = true" @mouseleave="showProducts = 
  false"  class="nav__list">home</div>
   <div class="nav__list">about</div>
    <div class="nav__list">pics</div>

<div class="nav__dropdown">

    <transition-group
      name="ballmove"
      enter-active-class="bouncein"
      tag="ul"
    >
      <li v-if="showProducts"  v-for="(menu, index) in todos" :key="index">{{menu.text}}</li>
    </transition-group>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ronoc4/eywraw8t/339253/

Answer (score 0):

`<transition-group>` is for animating (or transitioning) *individual* elements within a group (rows in a table, items in a list).

If you want to animate (or transition) the entire group as a whole, which I think is what you're asking, use `<transition>` instead.

```
<transition name="ballmove" ...>
    <ul v-if="showProducts">
        <li v-for="(menu, index) in todos" ...>
    </ul>
<transition>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I wanna be able to transition on the list the ballmove effect, and on the background I wanna be able to have a fade in effect. but I can't seem to do something like transition the div and a transition-group on the list elements

Answer (score 0):

I found adding a fade to the group then adding a transition class to the li got something that I was looking for. I was really wanted to have each item in the list load animation bouncein, so when you hover over a button the items in the list would load individually, but I guess what I've done will have to work for now.

```
 <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" >
   <ul v-if="showProducts">
     <li class="bouncein" v-for="(menu, index) in todos" ...>
   </ul>
 </transition>
```